# Open Sans font rendering issue in heading #3

Tags: bug, design

At least on my computer the lower case `i` and `j` looks awkward and misleading in heading level number 3 (`<h3>` or `###`).

This means the following sample block

```
#Every jack will find his jill.
##Every jack will find his jill.
###Every jack will find his jill.
```

yields this screenshot from my screen:

[image: sample Header #1, Header #2 and #3 of the text 'linebreak Ii']

and gets rendered like this on your monitor:

## Every jack will find his jill.

### Every jack will find his jill.

#### Every jack will find his jill.

---

As *@Zach Saucier* pointed out "*it's a font rendering error at certain sizes*" and interestingly when zooming in or out the text gets rendered properly …

How to fix this problem?

---

**Edit I:** I am using *Mozilla Firefox 45.0.1* on *Windows 7*

Comment: Interestingly enough it _also_ looks fine when you zoom out.

Comment: @Johannes: Yes you are right, as *Zach Saucier* pointed out *it’s a rendering error at a certain size* …

Comment: Reproduced in Internet Explorer 11 on Windows 10.

Answer (score 3):

I see it as well on Chrome, Firefox, and Edge on Windows 10.

There was a [Chrome bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=334574) that had a similar issue in the past (it says it's been fixed but it still has shown up on all of my devices for a couple years now).

Comment: I'm on Windows 7 with Chrome 49, also see the issue.

Comment: @Johannes Indeed. It's a rendering error for the font at certain sizes

Answer (score 0):

Looks fine for me:

[image]

Comment: Same here, looks perfectly alright

Comment: Looks fine for me too

Comment: I take it back; looks OK on mobile Chrome (Android M), but looks like elegent's issue on Opera 36 and Chrome 49